# NodeJS : smart JSON conversion to Excel file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, excel

I'm working in NodeJS and I would like to export a JSON-format object to an Excel file.

I am well aware that there are (at least) three npm packages for that purpose, but so far none of these gave me the output I'm dreaming of.

Here is the javascript object I have :

```js
var myObject = 
      {
        hashkey1 : {
          keyA : dataA1,
          keyB : dataB2
        }
        hashkey2 : {
          keyA : dataA2,
          keyB : dataB2
        }
      };
```

The .xls (or .xlsx)(or any spreadsheet format) of my dreams has one line for each hashkey. On each line : first column would be the hashkeyX, second column would be the dataAX, third column would be the dataBX.

Is it possible to achieve such a result using available tools, or do I have to code it from scratch ? Any advice to get anywhere near this result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write to csv (comma-separated values) text file without any additional library. This extension open in Excel by default.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.createWriteStream('file.csv', {'flags': 'w', autoClose: true});
var result = '';
for (var hashkey in myObject) 
    result += hashkey + ';' + myObject[hashkey].keyA + ';' + myObject[hashkey].keyB + '\n';
file.write(result);
```

Comment: Wonderful ! Worked on the first try on my whole database. I guess that was a newbie question with an easy solution but still, I upvote you with love considering that your snippet was simple and helpful !

Furthermore, I feel more secure building my own string the way I want, rather than using someone else's module. Thx a lot !