# Convert json object to csv output

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to convert a json object to a comma separated values. Here is the script I am working:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var json = fs.readFileSync('./file.geojson', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
if (err) throw err;
});
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
// console.log(obj);
var tags = [
obj.properties
];
var output = JSON.stringify(tags);
var headers = 'name,number';
console.log(output);
```

The script gives the output

```
[{"route":"1"}]
```

The output I am expecting is a comma separated values like below:

```
name,number
route,1
```

what part of converting to csv am I missing. Can anyone please help.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546182/nodejs-smart-json-conversion-to-excel-file/38546420#38546420

Comment: I really can't imagine this not having a million answers on **Google**...

Comment: Try this if you have complex json https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer your question, try something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var json = fs.readFileSync('./file.geojson', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
if (err) throw err;
});
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

var tags = [
obj.properties
];
var headers = 'name,number';

var output = headers + '\r\n';
for (var key in tags[0]){ // changed to tags[0]
  output += '"' + key + '",' + tags[key] + '\r\n'; 
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: I tried looking at other answers here and followed most of the steps. But for some reason I couldnt get the output I wanted. sorry :( 
@Hans Strausl I tried your way to convert it to csv here is how I am seeing the output as
`name,number`
`"0",[object Object]`. 
I tried using JSON.toString() but no change in the output. what am I missing here?

Comment: I updated my answer with a fix, the line `for (var key in tags){` should have read `for (var key in tags[0]){`

Comment: yeah now its working. thank you very much everyone :)